# Video with QML Video plays choppy on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, video, qml

I’m trying to create simple video player with QML. I have QtSdk installed and QtMobility compiled and installed from source. Then I put this simple video playing code to main qml file:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import QtMultimediaKit 1.1

Item{
    width: 400; height: 300
    Video {
        id: video
        source: "d:/Projects/Serenity - HD DVD Trailer.mp4"
        anchors.fill: parent
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                video.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After compiling and running application, video plays choppy and on exiting application it puts this in log:

```
2011-06-07 11:13:44.055 video-player[323:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10225ea60 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-06-07 11:13:45.007 video-player[323:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10264f030 of class __NSCFDate autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-06-07 11:13:45.007 video-player[323:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11a409000 of class NSCFTimer autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-06-07 11:13:45.008 video-player[323:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11a43e550 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-06-07 11:13:45.008 video-player[323:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11a462560 of class __NSFastEnumerationEnumerator autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

If any way to make it playing smoothly and to prevent memory?

Comment: You can get rid of the autorelease pool messages by creating a new autorelease pool at the beginning of your application, e.g. `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];`

Comment: What is the bit rate of the content file and have you tried one with a lower bit rate? I noticed a performance issue with the QML Video item on Ubuntu which I did not have when I used a QVideoWidget. If I recall correctly, I concluded that it could have been because the video renders to the underlying QGraphicsVideoItem in the QML case, while in the widget case it makes use of GStreamer's xvimagesink - so basically a case of rendering to a surface vs. rendering to a window. I don't know which backend Mac OS X uses but perhaps the performance issue is cross-platform.

Comment: have you tried other file formats ? what are the results ?

Comment: @Fredrik H, i dont know exactly, but its fullHD clip with high resolution. Yes, i have tried, it was 320*240 ogg movie and it was playing smoothly. But still were memory leaks warnings in log.    @Abhijith, Yes, i tried ogg file with lowest bitrate. It was plaing smoothly, but still where memory leaks warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I`ve used OpenGL for that. Works even better than Windows not-GL version. Here a code:

```
QDeclarativeView mainwindow;
mainwindow.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("./qml/app.qml"));
QGLFormat format = QGLFormat(QGL::DirectRendering); // you can play with other rendering formats like DoubleBuffer or SimpleBuffer
format.setSampleBuffers(false);
QGLWidget *glWidget = new QGLWidget(format);
glWidget->setAutoFillBackground(false);
mainwindow.setViewport(glWidget);
```

Note: Current QtMobility version (1.1) has a bug that do not allow playing video in OpenGL  rendering mode on Windows. So i used a native Qt rendering for win.